# Where is the num key on a hp stream 14

Tags: keyboard

Could anyone help me as I've just bought arma3 the game and I need to find my number key so I can change my view could anyone help me. I've tried looking on the keyboard and pressing different buttons but nothing works.

Comment: Have you looked in the manual? If you can't find "num lock" in there, please edit the question to add a link to the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop does not have a "numeric key pad", and that is why it does not have a "Num lock" button: it just wouldn't make any sense. Bottom line: you don't have it!
Maybe you could get an USB external key pad, although it's a bit of a stretch just to get a key!